# PHP Keep exif data using imagecopyresampled

Tags: php, exif

I'm wondering if is a way to keep exif data of original image in image created by imagecopyresampled function. My code:

```
$randomName = Functions::generate_random_string(10);
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
$imageSize = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
$ratio = 1 / ($imageSize[0] / $imageSize[1]);
$newWidth = 2560;
$newHeight = round($newWidth * $ratio);
$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $newWidth, $newHeight );
imagecopyresampled( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $imageSize[0], $imageSize[1] );
```

Works fine but in created image there is no exif data.

Comment: No. EXIF data is structured data embedded in the JPEG's comment field. Your new image, being an entirely NEW and separate GD image, will share nothing with the GD image created from the original photo. You'd have to extract the JPG comment field from the original file and apply it to the new one, but that's beyond the purview of GD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the exif data and save it to the database as meta data for the file.