# Resizing function rotates certain images

Tags: php, image, image-resizing

I wrote this php function to resize images:

```
function resizeImage($file,$width,$height){
    $size=getimagesize($file);
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
    imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$size[0],$size[1]);
    return $dst;
}
```

Unfortunately, certain images get rotated by 180 degrees when I use this function. What can I do about it?

Comment: It doesn't look like this code is doing any rotation. My guess would be that the orientation of these images is actually in the image exif data and that data is being removed by imagecopyresampled. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028044/php-keep-exif-data-using-imagecopyresampled

Comment: @gmfm Can I modify the function in such a way that it reads the rotation from the exif file and applies it to the resized image?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489742/php-read-exif-data-and-adjust-orientation

Comment: @gmfm Thanks. I took a look and could fix my function. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

gmfm gave me a useful link in the comments. Here is the corrected function:

```
function resizeImage($file,$width,$height){
    $size=getimagesize($file);
    $src=imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $dst=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
    imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$size[0],$size[1]);
    $exif=exif_read_data($file,'IFD0');
    if ($exif['Orientation'] == 3) {
      $dst=imagerotate($dst, 180, 0);
    }
    if ($exif['Orientation'] == 8) {
      $dst=imagerotate($dst, 90, 0);
    }
    if ($exif['Orientation'] == 6) {
      $dst=imagerotate($dst, -90, 0);
    }
    return $dst;
}
```